# Ways of Updating/Inserting Random dates in MySQL within a specific date and time range

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update/Insert random dates in SQL within a specified Date Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788285/how-to-update-insert-random-dates-in-sql-within-a-specified-date-range)

My MySQL database Table has the following columns:

```
Primary_ID, Begin_Date, End_Date, Timestamp
```

How do I update using phpmyadmin, selected rows with randomly generated begin_dates and timestamp within a specified date range (eg: 30 days in a month).
E.g of desired outcome

```
Primary_id--- Begin_Date -------------Timestamp

1.------------2008-09-02--------------2008-09-02 21:48:09

2.------------2008-09-03--------------2008-09-03 15:19:01

3.------------2008-09-14--------------2008-09-14 01:23:12

4.------------2008-09-27--------------2008-09-27 19:03:59
```

Date Range between 2008-09-01 and 2008-09-31.
Time is variable 24 hrs

I am a newbie, so a syntax that will work in phpmyadmin will help greatly.

We are making a presentation for a gym site with 500 members but the added member values all have the same begin date and time. Trying to separate them into different monthly registrations in the database, eg 50 people registered in August at different days and times, 35 people in October, etc.

When I try some of the answers here, I get this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$randomDate = rand(1,31)' at line 1. 
So ideally, a code I can copy and paste into phpmyadmin with minimal editing will be appreciated. In sequence if possible. For a total dummy to understand and execute with as close to one or two clicks as possible.

Comment: phpmyadmin is a php script interface for mysql, not a db engine or language.

Comment: What have you tried and what errors are you getting? StackOverflow isn't a "code this for me" site.

Comment: Well, it is by asking questions for answers to problems and trying those answers, and modifying it that a person learns how to solve her coding problems. Everyone , including you, was a noob at one time.

Comment: We don't "hand out" solutions. If we did, nobody would learn anything. The difference between noobs like you and when we were noobs is that we weren't asking for an answer. We were asking for guidance so we could find the answer on our own. If you don't want to put the legwork in yourself, hire a freelancer.

Comment: @Adrianne2011 Please understand that while everyone of every skill level is obviously welcome here, this is a *programmer's* Q&A site. Qualifying your question with statements like "*...For a total dummy to understand and execute with as close to one or two clicks as possible.*", isn't going to elicit much assistance from the community.

Answer (score 1):

I'd pull them all out with a simple MySQL call with a basic PHP script, put them into an array, run the array through a "date randomizer" and then, take the new array and update the database by ID. easy peasy. But, if can't do something this simple,you probably shouldn't be making a "presentation" for a gym. It gives the rest of us freelancers a bad name when someone can't do the basics. Not trying to be mean. Just saying, don't bite off more than you can chew.

EDIT:

Holy crap, you're whiny! I know that I'm going to regret this but here's a better breakdown (without writing it for you).

Get Database information from MySQL with PHP:

```
$result = //result from mysql query IE. "SELECT*FROM `database`" which results in an array of information.
```

Put that array through a "date randomizer" (in quotes because YOU make the function:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
for($i=0; $i<$num; ++$i)
{
    //run your "date randomizer" function for each date key
}
```

Update your Mysql with the new array that you got from your "date randomizer":

```
//run your MySQL query to UPDATE each rows date and information by ID
```

Very simple. I can't really break it down any further for you.

If your job is to write PHP, and you can't do this, you need to look for different work, regardless of your outbursts. You're a really mean person.

Comment: Another unhelpful answer. Thanks for nothing. In your life, you will need emergency help or aid, and someone will give you an answer like the one you just gave, or none at all. Very unhelpful.

Comment: I just told you how to do it. Don't be a complete ass. This makes me not want to type out the code for you.

Comment: He gave you a very helpful guideline on how to complete the task, and this is how you react? Because of this and your unwillingness to take the time to learn what you need to do in order to solve a very simple problem, you can expect no help from anybody here on SO. If you put as much effort into this problem as you do being as lazy as you are, you would have solved this problem by now.

Comment: If I knew what a date randomizer is and how to run an array through it, then I would not be asking this question, would I? What got me riled up is you suggesting I should not be trying to save my job that is feeding my kids in these hard times by not making this vital presentation. I am being open here and asking for help and direction. Also willing to learn as long as it helps. But it seems you guys don't want newbs here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: No, people have given you the answer you need (especially on your DUPLICATE of this question), and you didn't like it because "it was confusing" to you. You don't want to LEARN. You just want us to do the work. If that's what you think a "job" entails, then you certainly don't deserve that either.

Comment: Wow, my lil question has attracted the self righteous little boy. Why don't you find someone else to bug and leave me alone since you never even suggested an answer, or a way or anything. You are just here running your mouth.

Comment: Sure thing, sweetheart. I'll get right on an answer that you can understand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't write PHP for a living. If I did, I would be ashamed to ask for rudimentary help like this. But this was needed to get approval for the aspect of the project which I am involved in. Thanks all the same.